# Can this problem be solved by AI?

Tags: ai-design, classification

I am looking in to building a kind of troubleshooting web application. It would be a form that starts with a first question. Depending on the answer, you get a follow up question and so on until the app has qualified your problem in to a small group of problems. To me it sounds a bit like a decision tree but what I have read about them is that it is the internal structure of a model and not what I am looking for. My guess is that a model needs all the input variables at once and not like I am looking for that feeds it one parameter at a time.

At this time I do not know of any data available. With the client we could create the desired resulting problem groups and the questions as well.

Would it be possible to solve this with the help of AI instead of hand coding a lot of case switch statements? If so could you point me to what to read up on?

Comment: I could absolutely call it a troubleshooting app. The domain is in vetrenary medicine. Instead of calling the vet you would get the client to fill in this web form. It would determine if it is a serious state of your pet and then let the vet call the client. In other cases it would tell the client to book an appointment later that week. So the information in the app is static but constantly evolving to make better decisions. But that would be a manual task.